# One text classification model, two sets of target classes

Tags: classification, natural-language, multilabel, transformers

I am attempting to classify text sequences into two sets of labels - `class_1 = [A, B, C, D]`, `class_2 = [X, Y, Z]`. The model will be an instance of `BertForSequenceClassification` from Huggingface's Transformers. For each input sequence, the single model should predict one class from `class_1` and one class from `class_2`, as opposed to training two separate models for each set of classes.

What would be the best way to do this? I am thinking to just have a set of classes to output as:

```
{
   'A': 0,
   'B': 1,
   'C': 2,
   'D': 3,
   'X': 4,
   'Y': 5,
   'Z': 6
}
```

The model will then have 7 outputs. I will then deduce the two predicted classes as `class_1 = logits[:4].argmax(dim=-1)` and `class_2 = logits[4:].argmax(dim=-1)`.

1. Is this a reasonable approach? Or is there a better way to force a single model to predict one label from each of the 2 different sets of classes?
2. If this is a reasonable approach, then what is the best way to handle the loss function? CrossEntropyLoss takes in a model's output logits and corresponding label indices. This wouldn't work in my case. Would it be best to implement my own loss function which is the average of the CrossEntropyLoss between `logits[:4]` and `logits[4:]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You need two different target variables.

As you point out, if you use a softmax activation or cross-entropy loss on the union of the two label sets, then the information about one label set will be used to predict the other one. This isn't your intention, because a higher (lower) probability of `class_1` should not directly cause a lower (higher) probability of `class_2`.

But the solution is simple. Your proposal in (2) is a perfectly valid solution. A more general form, used in Pareto optimization, lets you prioritize one loss or the other:

$$
\mathcal L = \pi L_y(\hat y, y) + (1- \pi) L_z(\hat z, z)
$$
where $z,y$ are your two labels and $\hat y, \hat z$ are your predictions for the labels and $0 \le \pi \le 1$ is a hyper-parameter that prioritizes learning for $y$ when it is larger and prioritizes learning for $z$ when it is smaller. Your proposal coincides with choosing $\pi = 0.5$.

And for complete generality, $L_z$ and $L_y$ don't even have to be the same loss function. For instance, on some problem, a person might want to predict a categorical feature (like gender) and a continuous feature (like age). In that case, you could use two completely different loss functions.